# How can I exclude all transitive dependencies of a library in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

Practically I just want to port this Gradle code to SBT:

```
compile("group:name:version") {
  transitive = false
}
```

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you are:

```
libraryDependencies += "group" % "name" % "version" intransitive()
```

Comment: Causes follwoing warning during build: ```... but Maven repositories
[warn]   do not support intransitive dependencies. Use exclusions instead so transitive dependencies
[warn]   will be correctly excluded in dependent projects.```

Comment: @DonaldDuck That means your dependency is coming from Maven style repo (not e.g. Ivy). And since 'Maven repositories do not support intransitive dependencies' you have to exclude them manually using exclude: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies